# How to show that any arbitrary closed ball is compact in (X,d)?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space such that for each $x \in X$ there exists an $\epsilon _x >0$ with $cl(B(x,\epsilon _x))$ compact, where $cl(A)$ is closure of $A$. To show that $(X,d)$ is complete.

Attempt: Now I have proved the fact that if every closed ball in a metric space is compact then the metric space is complete. Now I am thinking if I can some how take a arbitrary closed ball in this question and by provided conditions I can show that the ball is compact. But I don't know how to do so.

Comment: Where did you find this problem? It is not correct.

Comment: Elements of Metric spaces by Manabendranath Nath Mukherjee page 170 question number 16(b).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. Example $(0,1)$ with the usual metric. Can you check that your hypothesis is satisfied here?

Comment: Yes you are right it is false. But this is a question from a excercise. I think that is then incorrect.